# Emberjs - trying to access model from controller: returns undefined

Tags: ember.js

In EmberJS I have my models defined as such:

```
App.Conversation = DS.Model.extend({
    body            : DS.attr('string'),
    created_at      : DS.attr('date'),
    entry           : DS.hasMany('Entry')
});

App.Entry = DS.Model.extend({
    body    : DS.attr(),
    conversation: DS.belongsTo('Conversation'),
    created_at : DS.attr('date'),    
});
```

And my Conversations controller like this:

```
App.ConversationsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({    
    actions: {
        event: function() {     
            var entry = this.store.createRecord('entry', {
                body: 'test test'
            });

            this.store.find('conversation', 102498).get('entry').createRecord(entry);
        },
    }
});
```

However I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRecord' of undefined " when I try to save the new Entry model.

The conversation with ID 102498 do indeed exist, as it is returned if I try to get it like this:

```
this.store.find('conversation', 102498)
```

What seems to be the problem? Thank you in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `store.find()` method returns promise it's not yet resolved when you call `get('entry')` on it.

Try this so it first resolves the promise then call `get('entry')` :

```
this.store.find('conversation', 102498).then(function(conversation){
 conversation.get('entry').createRecord(entry);
});
```

This should work, hope it helps.